Issue with installing wrf-python
i am not able to install wrf-python in linux. it always tells me that numpy module is not found however i have already installed numpy. can anyone help out.
tried pip, pipx, sudo, nothing is working. i have Python3. thanks in advance

Have you tried the installation instructions at https://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html ?
